# Avoid "-bash: __vsc_prompt_cmd_original: command not found" when launching Terminal from Python in macOS

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

I have a basic macOS app (PyQt5) that launches Terminal.app and executes a command in it:

```py
        cmd = f" cd {os.getcwd()};  bash -c ./backup.sh"
        subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', f'tell application "Terminal" to do script "{cmd}"'])
```

It works, however every command executed in this terminal produces this warning:

[image]

That bottom `ls` is me experimenting. I see the warning comes after each command has executed.

Googling I find an instruction to `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`. If I `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` from this newly created Terminal.app instance I get:

```
 pi@pis-MacBook-Pro ~/Desktop/tmp/tray 
> echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
update_terminal_cwd; __vsc_prompt_cmd_original history -a; history -c; history -r
-bash: __vsc_prompt_cmd_original: command not found
```

I'm running the app from VSCode's interactive terminal. Presumably this is related. However `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` from this interactive terminal gives:

```
(.venv) 
 pi@pis-MacBook-Pro ~/Desktop/tmp/tray 
> echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
__vsc_prompt_cmd_original
```

But I think VSCode is using iTerm2 for its interactive terminal. (The backcolour matches that of iTerm2 not Terminal).

My question is: **How to launch the Terminal.app without incurring this warning?**

If I try a preceding `unset PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```py
        cmd = f" unset PROMPT_COMMAND;  cd {os.getcwd()};  bash -c ./backup.sh"
        subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', f'tell application "Terminal" to do script "{cmd}"'])
```

... I still get an initial warning, even though it has now disappeared from subsequent commands executed in this new Terminal window:

[image]

EDIT: I tried running `python tray.py` from iTerm2 rather than from VSCode's terminal, but it doesn't change anything.

```
> echo $PROMPT_COMMAND  # from iTerm2
history -a; history -c; history -r
```

Comment: Run `declare -p` to print all your variables, exported to the environment and otherwise, and `declare -f` to print all your defined functions; search the results for that string.

Comment: Note that if this is coming through your PS1, it's bad form to export that (it's _also_ bad form to export a `PROMPT_COMMAND`, for that matter); ideally both are kept as shell-local variables well away from the environment, and if you can find the code that's letting them pollute the environment, you might consider fixing it.

Comment: Another generally helpful place to start is to run `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i` and search the log -- that'll tell you which file and which line was responsible for each variable that's set and every other operation that took place during initialization, should something untoward be coming from your dotfiles (or, generally, from content sourced at shell initialization time as opposed to inherited from a parent process).

Comment: BTW, `cmd = f" cd {os.getcwd()};  bash -c ./backup.sh"` is bad juju from a security perspective. An account that creates a directory with `mkdir -p $'/tmp/$(rm -rf ~/*)'` and then coerces a user to run your script inside it will cause that user's home directory to be deleted, even if the hostile account had no write access outside `/tmp`. It's always better to avoid invoking a shell at all, and if you _must_ invoke a shell, to use [`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) to escape content being substituted into code therein.

Comment: (I'd also use `&&` instead of `;` to connect the `cd` and the script execution so the script doesn't try to execute something from an incorrect directory if the `cd` fails, and just make it `cd ... && ./backup.sh` to avoid the inefficiency of a completely unnecessary/useless subprocess).

Comment: ...anyhow -- I _suspect_ that the reference may be coming, not from PROMPT_COMMAND but from PS1. Just a guess; searching `declare -p` and `declare -f` output as suggested above will give you a certain answer.

Comment: BTW, instead of using `unset` in the shell command, you can also use `del os.environ['PROMPT_COMMAND']` from your Python code. Similarly, if PS1 is set in the environment, you'll want to clear that too.